# Trying to import icons into home screen, getting white screen on emulator or unable to resolve module react-native-safe-area-context

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, icons

I am new to coding and have run into a problem while making a instagram clone...

I am trying to export some bottom tab icons from my BottomTabs.js component into my home screen (HomeScreen.js)

[BottomTabs/ bottomeTabIcons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgqAr.jpg)

[HomeScreen.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOF6B.jpg)

But when I try to show the icons by importing bottomTabIcons into homescreen.js, i get:

[Error when imoprting bottomTabIcons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJeeb.jpg)

And when I import BottomTabs I get:

[White Screen after importing BottomTabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5qa2.jpg)

And if I try reloading the emulator I get:

[This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgzbf.jpg)

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it, many thanks in advance

Comment: have you installed `react-native-safe-area-context` ? if yes, then maybe it's not properly linked

Comment: Thanks for the reply, turns out I need to install react-native-safe-area-context react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screen